# Replacing Strings in HTML with JSON key values

Tags: angular, angular-translate, angular-pipe

I have made translation that works, but text is changing only in one html component. Imports are correct, because I can use | translate method in differents components. Problem is with getting values from JSON file in other components. When I am writing `{{'keyValue.textForReplacing'|translate}}` my text appears like keyValue.textForReplacing. It is not imported from JSON file. What's more, I can use all my key: values objects from JSON file only in one html component.
I have used this as an example https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Maybe you have to use ``| async`` pipe for getting data from JSON then apply ``| translate`` pipe

Comment: Thanks, but when is just empty space :D.

Answer (score 0):

Try {{keyValue.textForReplacing|translate}}

Comment: Without ' ' or " " there's gonna be an error. I am just using as u said but with ' '.